# Trying to call a function in a Fragment from a different class

Tags: java, android, class, android-fragments

I need to call a function in my portfolioActivity Fragment which comes from the class portfolioListAdapter.
It says my parameters are incorrect.

This function works just fine when I'm not using a Fragment, but as I am linking my Fragment to a navigation drawer, it is necessary to keep it this way.

Here is my Fragment:

```
public class portfolioActivity extends Fragment {

    ListView portfolioList;
    String[] stockTicker={"AAPL", "GOOG", "MSFT"};
    double[] stockPrice={138.96, 830.63, 64.01};
    int[] shares={5, 2, 10};
    double[] percentChange={0.59, 0.55, 1.43};

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.portfolio_layout, container, false);

        portfolioList = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.portfolioListView);
        //ADAPTER
        ListAdapter adapter = new portfolioListAdapter(this, stockTicker, stockPrice, shares, percentChange);
        portfolioList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        getActivity().setTitle("Portfolio");
    }
}
```

The error comes when I try to call portfolioListAdapter().
It says there is a problem with the "this" parameter.

Here is my other class:

```
public class portfolioListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

//DECLARATIONS
String[] stockTicker={};
double[] stockPrice={};
int[] shares={};
double[] percentChange={};
Context c;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public portfolioListAdapter(Context context, String[] stockTicker,
                            double[] stockPrice, int[] shares, double[] percentChange) {

    super(context, R.layout.portfolio_row_model, stockTicker);

    this.c=context;
    this.stockTicker=stockTicker;
    this.stockPrice=stockPrice;
    this.shares=shares;
    this.percentChange=percentChange;
}

public class ViewHolder
{
    TextView stockTicker;
    TextView stockPrice;
    TextView shares;
    TextView totalValue;
    TextView percentChange;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView==null)
    {
        inflater=(LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.portfolio_row_model, null);
    }

    // OUR VIEWHOLDER OBJECT
    final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

    //INITIALIZE VIEWS
    holder.stockTicker= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_portfolio_ticker);
    holder.stockPrice= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_portfolio_price);
    holder.shares= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_portfolio_shares);
    holder.totalValue= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_portfolio_value);
    holder.percentChange= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_portfolio_change);

    //ASSIGN VIEWS
    holder.stockTicker.setText(stockTicker[position]);
    holder.stockPrice.setText(String.valueOf("$"+stockPrice[position]));
    holder.shares.setText(String.valueOf(shares[position]));
    holder.totalValue.setText(String.valueOf("$"+(stockPrice[position]*shares[position])));
    holder.percentChange.setText(String.valueOf(percentChange[position]+"%"));


    //return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    return convertView;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put code after `return`.

And your parameters **are** wrong. `this` is a Fragment, not a Context, you need to use `getActivity()` or (preferably) `onAttach` there.

```
private ListView portfolioList;
private PortfolioListAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    ( (Activity) context).setTitle("Portfolio");

    adapter = new PortfolioListAdapter(context, stockTicker, stockPrice, shares, percentChange);
    portfolioList.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.portfolio_layout, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    portfolioList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.portfolioListView);
}
```

Note: You also are not using the `ViewHolder` correctly.
Might want to read back over how to do that (or use a RecyclerView)

Comment: Thank you so much man, I've been struggling with this for hours. Also, what is wrong with the ViewHolder? I built most of my code while watching a video and that's where the guy placed it. My code is doing exactly what I want it to.

Comment: You never called `getTag()` or `setTag()`, and so if that code is from a tutorial, it also was doing it wrong. https://dzone.com/articles/optimizing-your-listview

Answer (score 0):

1) Can't put code after return.

2) Constructor for adapter is expecting a "Context" object. What you are passing is a fragment object(this)
Add this code fragment

```
private Context mContext;
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    mContext = context;
}
```

And in call to adapter pass mContext instead of this.